# Unify service endpoints in kubernetes

Tags: service, kubernetes, routes

Is it possible to "unify" the endpoints of single services running in kubernetes? For example I've two services:

1. User
2. Post

Both services are exposed using it's own port. E.g.: `http://localhost:30888/api/user` and `http://localhost:30884/api/post`.

Now I want a single interface like this:

`http://localhost:8080/api/user` and `http://localhost:8080/api/post`. How can I configure this?

The services are exposed using this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: post-service
  labels:
    app: post-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 44884
      nodePort: 30884
  selector:
    app: post
```

Comment: I personally use https://www.getambassador.io/ which you can just add to your service yaml to create the routing. Available with helm as a stable chart too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to add an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) on top of your Services. Ingresses can do a bunch of things including send traffic to different Services based on paths.

An Ingress to get you started might look something like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/user
        backend:
          serviceName: post-service
          servicePort: 44884
      - path: /api/post
        backend:
          serviceName: user-service
          servicePort: 33883 # Or whatever port your user-service is using
```

Behind the scenes, what makes an Ingress work varies depending on how you're running your Kubernetes cluster. For example, if you're using GKE, an Ingress is actually implemented as an [HTTP load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer). If you're using EKS, it's implemented as an [Application load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/kubernetes-ingress-aws-alb-ingress-controller/). Each load balancer has lots of features and options, but the big one you should know about before starting anything is they will cost additional money on top of running your cluster.

Edit:

As prometherion mentioned in the comments, Ingresses allow traffic from outside of your cluster. If you're running a publicly-exposed website of some type, this is probably what you want. However, if these are internal endpoints that should not be exposed to the outside world, you might want to investigate [service meshes from prometherion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57947240/868533) instead.

Comment: Yeah, Ingress resource could do the trick even it's considered to allow external traffic to inside the cluster: the question is not clear, so don't know if he want to expose internally or not.

Comment: Very good point and I agree that the question wasn't clear around external traffic. I updated my answer to mention that Ingresses allow external traffic and service meshes work better for intra-cluster traffic instead.

Comment: @prometherion I want to expose externally. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, using Kubernetes default resources, it's not possible: you have to use an available Service Mesh like [Istio](https://istio.io), [Maesh](https://mae.sh) or [Linkerd](https://linkerd.io/) or using a simple proxy according to your preferred flavor (NGINX, HAproxy or a simple GoLang application using `http/net` standard library).

I'm not a big expert of Istio (that's actually one of most used Service Mesh aroud available) but probably the [VirtualService](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/) could do the trick, along with *DestinationRule* resources.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: reviews-route
spec:
  hosts:
  - you-service.your-namespace.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - name: user-v1-routes
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/api/user"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: user-service.your-namespace.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
  - name: post-v1-route
    route:
    - destination:
        host: post-service.your-namespace.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/api/post"
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: user-destination
spec:
  host: user-service.yout-namespace.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
      app: user
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: post-destination
spec:
  host: post-service.yout-namespace.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
      app: post
```

YMMV and the YAMLs are just explanatory.